# Latency (Delay) in Lame Encoder

Tags: sound

I am using Lame encoder to encode my voice on one computer, send it to another and then decode it with ffmpeg and play it. It works very clearly but there is an awful delay in the voice. I know from another test that it is not at the receiving end. I believe it is being caused by Lame. Does anyone have this problem? Is there any way to make Lame run more quickly? Does anyone know of a quicker encoder? many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It would be useful to see the exact command lines that you are using for this process. Could these be added to your question?

Comment: int err = beEncodeChunk(hbeStream, ShortsToCompress, pWAVBuffer, OutBuff, &CompressedSize);
if (err != BE_ERR_SUCCESSFUL)
{
 beCloseStream(hbeStream);
 AfxMessageBox("beEncodeChunk() failed ");
 goto exit;
}
if (CompressedSize > 0)
{
 if (sendto(SoundGiveSock, (const char *)OutBuff, CompressedSize, 0, (struct sockaddr*)(&si_SoundGive), sizeof(si_SoundGive)) == -1)
 {
  AfxMessageBox("Failed to send sound packet to peer");
  goto exit;
 }
}

Comment: int err = beEncodeChunk(hbeStream, ShortsToCompress, pWAVBuffer, OutBuff, &CompressedSize);
if (err != BE_ERR_SUCCESSFUL)
{
 beCloseStream(hbeStream);
 AfxMessageBox("beEncodeChunk() failed ");
 goto exit;
}
if (CompressedSize > 0)
{
 if (sendto(SoundGiveSock, (const char *)OutBuff, CompressedSize, 0, (struct sockaddr*)(&si_SoundGive), sizeof(si_SoundGive)) == -1)
 {
  AfxMessageBox("Failed to send sound packet to peer");
  goto exit;
 }
}